# Synthesize in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@property @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032826/property-synthesize)

Explain the working or purpose of synthesize

Comment: Please check existing questions before asking a new. There already are several questions same as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, @synthesize automatically generates the getters and setters based on the @property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

synthesize used with property.When you declair a property in .h file then you need to synthesize that in .m file.

@synthesize creates getter and setter for your property.If you do not synthesize the property then you can use property.(it gives crash).

```
var=self.yourProperty (calling getter). simmiler to var=[self getYourProperty];

self.yourProperty=var (calling setter). simmiler to [self setYourProperty:var];
```

without synthesize you cant use the setter and getter.